# sms aggregator implementation/application

Tags: mobile, sms, gsm, gprs

What could be the use or application of SMS aggregators such as SMSLib or Kannel. 
Can I use them to send SMS's from my web server.

In case they can send SMS's will those be sent on a GSM channel or GPRS channel.

What would be the cost implications per sms on part of the customer and on part of my implementation process?

Comment: No such thing as "GPS channel"! You can't send data via GPS, only triangulate your current latitude/longitude based on GPS satellite positions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use those libraries/SDK's but you will still need to get a [short code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_code) to send and receive SMS text messages to and from a mobile device.

[OpenMarket](http://openmarket.com/) offers this type of service as well as a number of software SDK's to implement your request. Also OpenMarket offers Premium SMS as well as MMS.

It's a lot easier then Kannel ;)

BTW if you just looking to send SMS via a web page and know what carrier the user is you might want to try the [SMS gateway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_gateway) approach. It's using a special email address to send SMS to a mobile device, but I don't think they can reply to this type of message.

Comment: How do I get the facility of SMS gateway, do I have to approach a phone service provider, or is it provided free by some online websites?

Comment: The SMS Gateway approach is one way communication to a mobile device through a special carrier email, like for AT&T in the USA you can use these: 
number@txt.att.net (SMS)
number@mms.att.net (MMS)
But the catch is the mobile device can't reply to these types of messages. If you want true SMS capabilities you need to use an aggregator like OpenMarket

Comment: also for the SMS Gateway you need to know the end user's carrier to send to the right email address.

Comment: Email gateways are not supported in Europe. Only it is in USA, in some carrier and with limit in traffic. I will recomend you contract SMS Push provider for 1-direction comunication.

If you need 2-direction comunication, you have to contract short code with some sms aggregator.

Normaly, aggregators have HTTP, SMPP or web services interfaces to connecting them.